# How to use tab separator sep = "\t" in writing a .tsv file in R

Tags: r, csv, separator

I want to write a .tsv file and use the tab separator, `sep = "\t"`, but it seems it does not work. For example, I have this simple data

```
a<-c(5,1,0,3,2,0.6,1.6,7,9,0)
b<-c(11,0,1,18,11,11,0,13,20,10)
c<-c(10,20,0.7,0.8,0.3,0.4,0,0.9,1,1)

MAT<-cbind(a,b,c)
MAT<- as.data.frame(MAT)
```

Then I write this data into a .tsv file using

```
write.csv(MAT, "test.tsv", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE, sep = "\t")
```

However, when I tried to read test.tsv using

```
read.csv("test.tsv")
```

The result seems okay. But when I checked deeper using a command

```
more test.tsv
```

via the terminal, it shows that the separator is a `","` instead of a tab. Could please anyone explain why it happened? And how to make the tab separator `sep = "\t"` works instead of `","`?

Comment: Did it not warn you ``attempt to set 'sep' ignored``? You should use ``write.table()`` instead.

Comment: CSV stands for Comma Separated Values. If you don't want a comma separator, use `write.table`

Comment: As a side note, `as.data.frame(cbind(...))` should be avoided - it can cause problems when you have mixed data types because `cbind` creates a matrix. It's shorter, more efficient, and safer to directly use `MAT <- data.frame(A, B, C)`.

Comment: @user438383 yes it did, but the first file was fine tho using the write_csv, so Im confused.

Comment: @GregorThomas I see. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use function `write_tsv()` from package `readr` (csv is for coma separated, tsv is for tab separated)

Comment: You *can* use is more accurate than *should*, but yes, that's what I would recommend. I would probably call it a tidy solution too, that's what I recommend students look for when searching since that's what I teach.